# RSpec and Cancancan: all negative tests failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, cancan, cancancan

Can anyone help me to understand why only my negative (i.e., `should_not`) tests would be failing? All my `should` tests are passing, so it makes me think I've got some configuration thing wrong, although what I've no idea.

**ability.rb**

```
# encoding: utf-8
#
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    @user = user || User.new
    if @user.administrator?
      administrator_abilities
    elsif @user.client?
      client_abilities
    elsif @user.guest?
      guest_abilities
    end
    can :read, :share
  end

  private

  def administrator_abilities
    can :manage, :all
    can [:index, :filter, :new, :create], :administration
  end

  def client_abilities
    cannot :manage, administrator_resources
    can :manage, [:account, :provider_auth, :user_auth]
    can :read, [Component, Cover, Introduction, Template]
    can :manage, client_made_resources, user_id: @user.id
  end

  def guest_abilities
    cannot :manage, client_made_resources
    cannot :manage, administrator_resources
    can :create, Expression
  end

  def client_made_resources
    [Authorisation, Document, Component,
     CustomArticle, EditedArticle, Invoice, Order, Photo]
  end

  def administrator_resources
    [Brand, Chart, Component, Cover, Expression, Introduction, Mode,
     Preference, Price, Template, User, UserNote]
  end
end
```

**user_spec.rb**

```
# encoding: utf-8
#
require 'spec_helper'
require 'cancan/matchers'
def client_made_resources
  [Authorisation, Document, Component, CustomArticle, EditedArticle, Invoice,
   Order, Photo]
end

def administrator_resources
  [Brand, Chart, Component, Cover, Expression, Introduction, Mode, Preference,
   Price, Template, User, UserNote]
end

RSpec.describe Ability do
  let(:user) { create(:user, state: 'guest') }
  subject    { Ability.new(user) }

  context 'guest' do
    client_made_resources.each do |r|
      it "should not be able to manage client's #{r}" do
        expect(subject).to_not be_able_to(:manage, r.new)
      end
    end
```

Every negative test has this result:

```
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:69 # Ability guest should not be able to manage client's Document
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an answer for you. Some tips though: Maybe you should move all the cannots to a single block that is run first? That would reduce duplication and be safer in case a user falls through all the role checks. Also once you say administrator "can :manage, :all" there is no need for additional definitions. :manage covers every action and :all covers every object.

Comment: Also if you make the resources lists a class constant or class method, you can directly refer to them in the test and don't have to worry about keeping the lists in sync between both files.

Comment: As for the error, have you verified that user.administrator? and user.client? are actually false for your factoried object? We would need to see the model and factory to fully know what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I've made a module with the relevant permission methods. The factory by default is a `client` so if that was the case at least the client tests should be passing. Real stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why but I've refactored my tests and they now work as expected. Maybe this'll help someone.

```
RSpec.describe User do
  describe 'Abilities' do
    context 'guest' do
      let(:user) { create(:user, state: 'guest') }
      (client_made_resources + administrator_resources).each do |r|
        it "cannot manage #{r}" do
          ability = Ability.new(user)
          assert ability.cannot?(:manage, r.new)
        end
      end

      it 'can read shares' do
        ability = Ability.new(user)
        assert ability.can?(:read, :share)
      end
...
```

Comment: Looks like maybe the issue is with the be_able_to matcher then. If you can replicate it in a simple app, file a bug report. It looks like the cancan repo by ryanb is not maintained any more, though. You might want to check out this fork for a newer version: https://github.com/cancancommunity/cancancan